# Flutter Provider vs global variables

Tags: flutter, provider

what is the reason for using Provider (in a simple app) on top of global variables defined in the main file?
calling Provider has to be embedded in Build methods, so can be a direct access to global varialbes prvided the main is imported

are the widgets calling Provider somehow automatically marked for rebuild if variables are changed?

until now I am using both Provider and direct access to learn the differences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A global in Dart is not "observable".  You can locate the variable, and obtain its current value, but there's no place to register to be informed of changes. This is particularly important if you are including the data as part of a view, or as part of data that is further observed.

The various state management solutions (including Provider, and my preferred system, Riverpod) are all mechanisms to implement "observable data", which provides three key features: locatability, current value, and registration of ongoing notifications.

Riverpod in addition has the ability to "override" the locatability, which comes in handy for testing or dependency injection.

Comment: thanks for explanation and clarification, still need time to understand it all, but moving forward

Answer (score 2):

> are the widgets calling Provider somehow automatically marked for rebuild if variables are changed?

Yes! Although maybe not exactly how you think it works. `provider` is built in a very similar manner to how `InheritedWidget` is built in the framework. When you call its `of` method (or `context.watch`), what you really do is call [`dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html) on the `BuildContext` of your widget (which context you pass to it). This registers the element of that widget to be rebuilt whenever the *dependency* (the providing widget) *changes* calling `didChangeDependencies` and then the `build`.

If you provide an ordinary class, it won't get *changed* unless you use a `Provider.value` and changed the object returned in `value`. If you provide a `ChangeNotifier` with `ChangeNotifierProvider`, it will *change* whenever a `notifyListeners` on it was called, etc.

Shall you use a raw `InheritedWidget`, you would have control over when the dependents (widgets that call `Provider.of`) shall get updated with a [`updateShouldNotify`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget/updateShouldNotify.html) boolean getter.

You can also achieve this with `provider` by filtering what needs to change for the widget rebuild to be invoked with `context.select`. It's basically a `context.watch`, but you pass a callback to it and whenever the value returned changes, a rebuild is triggered, e.g.:

```dart
final someVariable = context.select<DeviceProvider, int>((p) => p.someVariable);
```

While using `provider`/`InheritedWidget` you can wrap you widget tree with a new `Provider`/`InheritedWidget` to change the instance that will be provided down the tree. It can also handle disposing the values when the provider is removed from the tree. With global variables, you'd have to do that manually. Also in widget tests you'd have to set and clean the global variable yourself. To have multiple instances of the same class instantiated for different widget trees you can simply use a few `Provider`s, and with global variables you'd need to create a new variable.

Please read the below thoroughly to better understand how these work inside:

- [provider | Flutter Package - Usage](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#usage)
- [InheritedWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html)

Comment: thanks for explanation and clarification, still need time to understand it all, but moving forward

Comment: in this case  "an indirect subscription" is a challenge  context.watch<DeviceProvider>().someVariable means both: get the variable value, but also "subscribe" to variable changes and mark widget for rebuild at changes

Comment: @piotr I edited my answer to include selecting on a particular variable from provided class

Comment: thanks for the explanation here on stackOverflow :) I got the idea of provider from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUDhozpnTUw I undertand it and use in my apps. The google clips on widgets, sync, streams are great as well But I had no luck with keys and inherited widget, I watched it 10+ I did not get it :(  I hope that your answer make me get it at last

Comment: a question regarding FrogColor example: if I "wrap" entire widget tree in FrogColor: can I use  FrogColor.of with every context down there, even 5 levels deeper?                                                                                                               body: FrogColor(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext innerContext) {
            return Text(
              'Hello Frog',
              style: TextStyle(color: FrogColor.of(innerContext).color),

Comment: and one last question: how do we set/change a color of FrogColor? In the example I can find accessing the FrogColor color

Comment: Yes, the `FrogColor.of(context)` will work for **all** descendant widgets' contexts. You can change it by changing the `color` you passed to `FrogColor`. Make sure the `FrogColor` is rebuilt, so if it's inside `StatefulWidget`, you need to call `setState`. If you want to change it from somewhere down the widget tree, you'd need to do something like this: Wrap your `FrogColor` inherited widget in a stateful widget, where the color would be for example `ValueNotifier`. In its `build`, wrap the inherited widget with `ValueListenableBuilder` so the inherited widget rebuilds whenever the color does

Comment: The inherited widget would hold the `ValueNotifier`, you can return it directly from its `of(context)` method, or you can only return `notifier.value` from `of()` and make something like `setColorOf(context, color)` which would do `notifier.value = color`. It's really worth another question on StackOverflow, not explaining in the comments 

Comment: Inherited widgets only pass themselves down the widget tree so that's why you needed that surrounding widget to keep it in the state and rebuild the inherited widget.